# Django app urls not working properly

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

I have the following base urls file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^agenda/', include('planner.urls', namespace='planner', app_name='planner'))
]
```

And my planner app contains the following urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^', SkirmList.as_view(), name='agenda'),
    url(r'^skirm/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', SkirmDetailView.as_view(), name='skirmdetailview'),
)
```

The problem I am having is when going to: http://localhost:8000/agenda/skirm/41/
It keeps loading the SkirmList view instead of the SkirmDetailView.

It's propably obvious to most but I am a beginner with Django. Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: The regular expression in the first url in planner.app might need something extra: `url(r'^$', SkirmList.as_view(), name='agenda'),`. At the moment it matches everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex `r'^'` matches any string. It just says the string needs to have a start. Every string has a start, so...

You need to include an end anchor as well:

```
url(r'^$', ...)
```

This regex looks for the start of the string, followed immediately by the end, i.e. an empty string. It won't match the `/agenda/skirm/41/` url.

Comment: Yes! that's it! I have been struggling with this for 2 days xD. Thanks!

Comment: Mark as answered please if that is the case. :)

Comment: Yeah, I had to wait a few minutes till I could ;)